# Single queue but distributed consumer for chat application

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

How to define distributed cosumer for single RabbitMQ queue where only one consumer process message at a time?

So far I have tried to use `channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=1, global=False)`

Also tried to use `channel.declare_queue(exclusive=True)` as well but no luck so far.

Being a chat application we want to process messages sequentially. How to address this problem?

We don't want consumer on single server because if anytime that single machine goes down then everything will stop.

Please note as we want to distribute consumer between multiple server so channel/connection object can't be same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [exclusive flag](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume.exclusive)?

It seems it could fit your use case, ensuring a single consumer, still having the fallback consumer(s) trying to connect on a regular basis so they can continue the work if the previously active consumer were to fail.

Comment: As mentioned above I have already tried it. We are getting the below error:

`[Yesterday 18:12] Bhanu Pratap Singh
aiormq.exceptions.ChannelLockedResource: RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'uat_old_data_queue' in vhost '/'. It could be originally declared on another connection or the exclusive property value does not match that of the original declaration.`

Comment: @Gaurav Pant You had tried defining your **queue** as exclusive, while I was talking about configuring the **consumer** as exclusive

Comment: consumer from the same channel with exclusive = True may work but here connection & channel objects are different. the common element is queue only when we talk about distributed consumers.

Comment: First, I do understand that the single active consumer might be a better fit to the use case than the consumer exclusive flag. But I didn't see any restriction to the flag regarding a need for common connection and channel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "single-active-consumer" to achieve the same. For more detail refer - https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer

```
queue = await channel.declare_queue(name=self.queue_name,arguments={"x-single-active-consumer": True})
```